# cannot import keras in anaconda

Tags: deep-learning, keras, anaconda

I installed keras in anaconda by pip install keras.I installed tensorflow and can import it.But iam not able to import keras.It shows

```
 File "<ipython-input-2-88d96843a926>", line 1, in <module>
    import keras

ImportError: No module named 'keras'
```

Comment: Are you using an environment ?

Answer (score 1):

look for the installed packages
pip list
or try conda install
may be more than one python exists

Comment: i have python 3.5 and pythn 3.4.Is that the problem??

Comment: No module named 'keras' means not installed
may be installed but for python 2.x